# Conditional independence isn't guaranteed when specifying the marginal distributions?

Tags: distributions, independence, graphical-model

It was mentioned very briefly in a lecture related to graphical models that two random variables $X_3$ and $X_4$ are both dependent on $X_2$.  But even when conditioned on $X_2$, the two variables $X_3$ and $X_4$ could be dependent through some other means.

I wasn't sure what the person meant by this, below is an example provided:

Random variables: $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$ with the following density functions.

$X_1 \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$
$X_2 \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$
$X_3 \mid (X_1,X_2) \sim \mathcal N(X_1+X_2,\sigma^2)$
$X_4 \mid X_2 \sim \mathcal N(aX_2+b,1)$

The above specification doesn't necessarily mean that:

$p(x_3,x_4|x_2)=p(x_3|x_2)p(x_4|x_2)$

Meaning the conditional independence does not necessarily hold between $X_3$ and $X_4$ given $X_2$.  The graphical model shows that the conditional independence will hold, but the specification I provided above does not guarantee it.

Comment: Do you mean that two marginal distributions for $X$ and $Y$, $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ respectively, don't dictate the joint distribution $P(X,Y)$?  The "independent" in "independent random variables" makes it a different question than your title indicates...

Comment: @jbowman (+1). Yes, I fear that choice of words could be unintended. Hopefully the OP can clarify.

Comment: Thanks for looking this over, I've provided the example the lecturer used.

Comment: In your updated version, are there typos?  For example, is $h$ a function of two variables as in $h(x_4,x_2)$ or one variable as in $h(x_2)$?  Is there a claim that $X_3$ and $X_4$ _are_ (conditionally) independent given the value of $X_2$, but yet $p(x_3,x_4\mid x_2) \neq p(x_3\mid x_2)p(x_4\mid x_2)$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: (+1) I'm also struggling with the notation. Do you think $p(x_4)$ is the probability mass function of $X_4$? If so, how could it depend on $x_2$ except in a trivial scenario?

Comment: Apologies, didn't mean to use $h$ twice.

Comment: When you write: $p(x_3) = g(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, is that supposed to mean $p(x_3 | x_1, x_2) = g(x_1, x_2, x_3)$? Or, perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: I'm very sorry for confusing everyone about this, I was trying to convey a general example which made sense in my head but I realize now makes no sense with the notation I used.  So I've edited with a more concrete example.

Comment: I've made one additional minor edit. Please check that it hasn't changed your intended meaning.

Comment: Thanks, I think it makes it more clear.  I've noticed a lot of books don't specify conditionals in their statements even when their density formula shows the dependence, is this just to reduce clutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question and the OP's lecturer's claims seem to indicate misunderstanding
of the notions of independence and conditional independence of random variables.
Different sets of distributions for *Bernoulli random variables* $X$, $Y$,
and $Z$ are presented here to illustrate the differences between various
notions.

- Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are known to be *independent* Bernoulli random variables
  with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.  Thus, their probability mass functions (pmf) are
  $$p_X(0) = p_X(1) = \frac{1}{2}; ~ p_Y(0) = p_Y(1) = \frac{1}{2}$$
  and their joint pmf is the product of the (marginal) pmfs
  $$p_{X,Y}(i,j) = p_X(i)p_Y(j) = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2} =  \frac{1}{4} ~\text{for all} ~ i, j \in \{0, 1\}$$
  Are $X$ and $Y$ necessarily *conditionally independent* given $Z$ where $Z$ is also
  a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$?  **Not necessarily.**  Suppose that $Z$ has parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ and consider the probability distributions 
  $$\begin{align*}p_{X,Y\mid Z}(i,j\mid Z=0) 
  &= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}, & i = j\\
  0, & i \neq j,
  \end{cases}\\
  p_{X,Y\mid Z}(i,j\mid Z=1) 
  &= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}, & i \neq j\\
  0, & i = j,
  \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
  $$
  The law of total probability shows that these conditional distributions
  combine to give the known joint pmf of $X$ and $Y$.  It is also
  easy to verify that regardless of 
  whether $Z = 0$ or $Z = 1$, both $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally distributed
  as Bernoulli random variables with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$, but
  $X$ and $Y$ are *not conditionally independent* given $Z$, regardless of
  whether $Z$ has value $0$ or $1$. In one case, we have $X = Y$, and in
  the other, $X = 1-Y$.  Thus we can say the following

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with known marginal
>   distributions, then their joint distribution is the product of the
>   marginal distributions. However, $X$ and $Y$ *need not be conditionally 
>   independent* even if the conditional marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$
>   are the same as their given unconditional marginal distributions. Thus
>   the conditional joint distribution of *unconditionally* independent random 
>   variables need not be the product of the conditional marginal distributions.

- Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z = 0$ 
  and also conditionally independent given $Z = 1$.  Are $X$ and $Y$ *necessarily
  unconditionally independent*?  **Not necessarily,** not even if $Z$ is a Bernoulli
  random variable with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.  Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are
  conditionally independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$ if
  $Z = 0$ and parameter $q$ if $Z = 1$.  Thus, the conditional joint pmfs are
  $$\begin{align*}
  p_{X,Y\mid Z}(0,0\mid Z = 0) &= (1-p)^2;
  \qquad \quad p_{X,Y\mid Z}(0,0\mid Z = 1) = (1-q)^2;\\
  p_{X,Y\mid Z}(0,1\mid Z = 0) &= p(1-p);
  \qquad \quad p_{X,Y\mid Z}(0,1\mid Z = 1) = q(1-q);\\
  p_{X,Y\mid Z}(1,0\mid Z = 0) &= p(1-p);
  \qquad \quad p_{X,Y\mid Z}(1,0\mid Z = 1) = q(1-q);\\
  p_{X,Y\mid Z}(1,1\mid Z = 0) &= p^2;
  \qquad \quad \, \qquad p_{X,Y\mid Z}(1,1\mid Z = 1) = q^2;
  \end{align*}$$
  Suppose that $p \neq q$. Then, $X$ and $Y$ are unconditionally independent 
  only in the trivial cases when $Z$ has parameter $\lambda$ equal to $0$ or
  $1$ (when one of the above two joint pmfs has weight $0$ in the total probability
  formula.

> If $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$, they need not be
>   unconditionally independent.

Is there any instance where conditional independence guarantees
unconditional independence?  If $X$ and $Y$ are not only
conditionally independent given $Z$ **but also have the same
conditional joint distribution for all choices of $Z$** then
$X$ and $Y$ are unconditionally independent.  But this is also
a trivial special case because the necessary condition means
that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are mutually independent random variables,
and so the conditional joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ does
not depend on the value of $Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation.  So is the first example you describe where $X$ and $Y$ are unconditionally independent but conditionally dependent given $Z$ the same concept of 'explaining away' in graphical models?

Comment: The concept of explaining away in directed graphical models requires $Z$ to be dependent on $X$ and $Y$, but I don't think your example requires such a claim. 
$$\begin{align*}p_{X,Y\mid Z}(i,j\mid Z=0) 
&= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}, & i = j\\
0, & i \neq j,
\end{cases}\\
p_{X,Y\mid Z}(i,j\mid Z=1) 
&= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}, & i \neq j\\
0, & i = j,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
The way you specify the conditional joint distribution, $Z$ does not necessarily have any dependence on $X$ or $Y$.  Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: "The way you specify the conditional joint distribution, Z does not necessarily have any dependence on X or Y. Am I correct in saying this?"  No, $Z$ _is_ dependent on $X$ and $Y$. $$\begin{align*}P\{X=0,Y=1,Z=1\}&=P\{X=0,Y=1\mid Z=1\}P\{Z=1\}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} \neq P\{X=0\}P\{Y=1\}P\{Z=1\}=\frac{1}{8}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you for providing such a thorough example.  This makes much more sense now as I begin review my elementary probability.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a long and argumentative answer with the first part being somewhat philosophical and the second part being most relevant to the question asked here.

In *probability theory,* independence is usually 
an *assumption* that is given as part of the problem statement
as in "Let $A$ and $B$ denote independent events" or "Let $X$ and $Y$
denote independent random variables" and this means that the events
or random variables enjoy a property that does not hold for events
or random variables in general.  Specifically,
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$
and
$$P\{X \in \mathcal A, Y \in \mathcal B\} =P\{X \in \mathcal A\}P\{Y \in \mathcal B\}$$
for all sets $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ in the $\sigma$-algebra.  Independence
of random variables $X$ and $Y$
implies the more commonly used statement
$$P\{X \leq a, Y \leq b\} = F_{X,Y}(a,b) 
=  P\{X \leq a\}P\{Y \leq b\} = F_{X}(a)F_{Y}(b), \forall a, b$$
as well as $p_{X,Y}(a,b) = p_X(a)p_Y(b)~ \forall a, b$ for discrete
random variables and
$f_{X,Y}(a,b) = f_X(a)f_Y(b)~\forall a, b$ for continuous random variables (note that
independence of continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ implies joint
continuity of $X$ and $Y$).  Let us call this the product rule.

In practical applications, where $X$
and $Y$ are random variables modeling physical phenomena,
things are not quite so straightforward.  If $X$ and $Y$ are arising
from distinct physically unrelated sources, we take them to be
independent and apply the product rule.  Note that there is
no *proof* of independence, only a general feeling that one 
phenomenon does not affect the other and so independence is
a reasonable assumption.  In some cases, of course, beauty
might lie in the eye of the beholder (or the author, reviewer,
and editor) but might be completely invisible to the general
reader.  But the notion is that *physical independence,* whether
such independence is assumed or a reasonable argument made in
support thereof, justifies the use of the product rule.

A third form of independence is *stochastic* independence:
$A$ and $B$ are said to be independent events if $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.
*Physical independence implies stochastic independence but the
converse need not be true.*  Here is an example whose underlying
idea might be familiar to the reader in the guise of coin-tossing.

> Consider an Exclusive-OR (XOR) circuit whose inputs $X$ and $Y$ are
>   are *physically independent* Bernoulli random variables taking on values
>   $0$ and $1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.  Physically independent
>   because they are coming from physically independent sources, say
>   from two different data packets sent by two  different computers
>   in two different parts of the country. The output $Z = X \oplus Y$ has value
>   $1$ exactly when one of $X$ and $Y$ has value $1$ and the other has value
>   $0$. It is easy to show that $Z$ is also a Bernoulli random variable
>   with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.   Now, $Z$ is clearly **physically dependent** 
>   on $X$ -- the output of an XOR circuit *should* depend on its inputs --
>   but $Z$ and $X$ are **stochastically independent** random variables:
>   $$\begin{align*}
> p_{X,Z}(0,0) &= P\{X = 0, Z = 0\} = P\{X = 0, Y = 0\} = p_{X,Y}(0,0) = \frac{1}{4}
> = p_X(0)p_Z(0)\\
> p_{X,Z}(0,1) &= P\{X = 0, Z = 1\} = P\{X = 0, Y = 1\} = p_{X,Y}(0,1) = \frac{1}{4}
> = p_X(0)p_Z(1)\\
> p_{X,Z}(1,0) &= P\{X = 1, Z = 0\} = P\{X = 1, Y = 1\} = p_{X,Y}(1,1) = \frac{1}{4}
> = p_X(1)p_Z(0)
> \\p_{X,Z}(1,1) &= P\{X = 1, Z = 1\} = P\{X = 1, Y = 0\} = p_{X,Y}(1,0) = \frac{1}{4}
> = p_X(1)p_Z(1)
> \end{align*}$$
>   Similarly, $Y$ and $Z$ are stochastically independent but physically dependent
>   random variables.

Thus, stochastic independence does not necessarily mean physical
independence; it might just be an artifact of the probability
assignment.  If we re-work the above example with $X$ and $Y$ 
physically independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter
$p \in (0,1), ~ p \neq \frac{1}{2}$, then we see that $Z$ is no
longer stochastically independent of $X$.  Thus, the independence
of $X$ and $Z$ is an artifact of the probability assignment or the
possibility that when the model was being devised, the hypothesis
$p = \frac{1}{2}$ did not get rejected because the test did not
give a statistically significant result!

---

---

Currently  studies that can be 
tarred broadly as saying "Everything is independent unless someone beats
me on the head and says it is not." seem to be in great vogue.

---

---

Turning to the OP's edited question,

> Random variables: $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$ with the following density functions.
>
> $X_1 \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$
>   $X_2 \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$
>   $X_3 \mid (X_1,X_2) \sim \mathcal N(X_1+X_2,\sigma^2)$
>   $X_4 \mid X_2 \sim \mathcal N(aX_2+b,1)$
>
> The above specification doesn't necessarily mean that:
>
> $p(x_3,x_4|x_2)=p(x_3|x_2)p(x_4|x_2)$

Note that *nothing* is said about whether $X_1$ and $X_2$ are
independent, whether physically or stochastically, nor is
anything said about independence or lack thereof of $X_3$ and $X_4$.
Are they all assumed to be independent because everything is
independent?

The conditional joint density of $X_3$ and $X_4$ given
$X_2$ *cannot* be computed from the given information, and so 
whether or not the product rule 
$$p(x_3,x_4|x_2)=p(x_3|x_2)p(x_4|x_2)$$
holds or not cannot be determined from the given information.
In any case, there seems to be no obvious reason why the
product rule *should* hold, and I don't see the faiure as
being indicative of anything except that the assumption of
independence everywhere does not seem to be working here.