# Is there a reliable algorithm to identify a low-dimensional log-linear model that fit high-dimensional data (if one exists)?

Tags: categorical-data, algorithms, log-linear

I am working with data from a complex survey, with over 100 variables per observation. From this I will be selecting 30 to 40 variables. All variables are categorical, with number of levels ranging from 2 to 23, with a mean of about five.

I would like to summarize my data with a log-linear model that highlights the important correlations between these variables without prematurely imposing a causal structure on the model. I am still doing coding and data cleanup, but I am pretty sure that I will not be able to implement the complete saturated model and then work my way down by testing whether I can knock off high-level interaction terms, as most of the texts seem to advise me to do. If I am understanding this correctly, the saturated model would contain about 900 quintillion coefficients. I'm using R, and I don't think all those coefficients are going to fit in my 4 gig of RAM. Also, in the smallest unit of geography that I am examining, there are only about 50,000 observations. 19 quadrillion coefficients per observation will leave me short a few degrees of freedom. So if this project is to be feasible, I would need to find a model that fits reasonably well without needing more than a 5th- or 6th-order interaction for any combination of variables.

My hope was to build up some blocks of mutually independent variables that I could count on excluding from groups of variables with higher-order interactions. However, considerable cold water was thrown on this notion by the answer to my last question, that mutually independent variables can nonetheless be correlated conditional on additional variables not in the original set. See: [Does independence imply conditional independence?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51322/does-independence-imply-conditional-independence). This implies that, for example, three mutually independent variables could nonetheless participate in obligatory 4- or 5-way interactions

So my question is, does anybody know of good algorithms for finding reasonably well-fitting log-linear models for high-dimensional data that are not egregiously invalid and that do not require that you start with a fully saturated model and work down?

Here is one that I was wondering about, but I am not too attached to it, and you should skip the rest of these ramblings if you are aware of an algorithm that is known to work. Is it reasonable to assume that models will not completely skip two or more levels? For instance, if five variables are not nested in any models that require 6th- or 7th-order interactions, is it reasonable to assume that, in real data not artificially designed to display odd patterns of correlation, that they will not be nested in any models that require  interactions of 8th order or higher? Suppose, for example, I end up with 30 variables. Then I could examine all the 4000-odd 3-variable combinations and identify those that require a three-way interaction.  For those that do not, I could test all the 4-way combinations that contain those three variables, and if there are none,  I can truncate the model at the two-way level for those three variables, as a 5-way interaction would involve skipping two levels. Similarly, for the three-variable combinations that do require a three-way interaction, I can test all the five-variable combinations that contain them.  If there are none, truncate. Whenever I find an n-way interaction that is required, I search the n+2 variable space, adding new highest-required-interaction-levels wherever I find them, and truncating wherever I do not.  In the end, I have a single structure of hierarchical models where we always know for any interaction term not contained in a higher-level interaction that there are no interactions that are one or two levels higher, and so, by assumption, that there are no required higher-level interactions.

Of course, I would have to do all this on just half my data, so I could use the other half to test whatever hypothetical structure I might find.

All that would be rather clever if I actually had any reason to believe hierarchical log-linear models can not skip two steps.  I suppose that if none of the triples that do not need a 3-way interaction term are embedded in 5-ples that require a 5-way interaction without there being one or more intervening required 4-way interaction terms, that would lend some support to the hypothesis.  I could actually test that.

I would be very grateful for whatever thoughts people could offer.