# Can graphical models represent independence besides conditional independence?

Tags: graphical-model

In a graphical model, two random variables are conditional independent given their common ancestors.

Can graphical models represent independence besides conditional independence?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if two random variables are independent, you just have two nodes with no edges between them.

Comment: How would you construct a Bayesian network for the example given by [Antonio Valerio Miceli-Barone](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/21523/antonio-valerio-miceli-barone) in his answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51325/164181)? It seems to me that you need an edge from X to B and an edge from A to B. However, A and B are mutually independent.