# Conditional independence statements for probabilistic motivation for linear regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, independence, graphical-model, conditional-independence

So the motivation for using the squared loss in linear regression can be written as the following (I think):

Assume $\{(\mathbf{x}_i, y_i) \mid i = 1, \dots n\}$ are repeated independent samples from random variables $\mathbf{X}$ and $Y$ respectively. With $Y \mid \mathbf{X} \sim N(f(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{w}), \sigma^2)$.

We then can write that:

$$
p(y_1, \dots y_n \mid \mathbf{x}_1, \dots \mathbf{x}_n; \mathbf{w}, \sigma) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}{p(\mathbf{x}_i,y_i;\mathbf{w}, \sigma)}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}{p(\mathbf{x}_i;\mathbf{w}, \sigma)}} \\
    = \prod_{i=1}^{n}{p(y_i \mid \mathbf{x}_i;\mathbf{w}, \sigma)}
$$

And therefore under the distributional assumption the log-likelihood is given by:

$$\begin{align}
  \log(p(y_1, \dots y_n \mid \mathbf{x}_1, \dots \mathbf{x}_n; \mathbf{w}, \sigma)) = C + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(y_i - f(\mathbf{x}_i;\mathbf{w}))^2}}{2\sigma^2}
\end{align}$$

And hence the MLE of $\mathbf{w}$ is given by solving the least squares problem.

---

Above we assumed $(\mathbf{x}_i, y_i) \perp (\mathbf{x}_j, y_j)$ for $i \neq j$.

But I think we can get the same with just assuming conditional independence i.e $y_i \mid \mathbf{x}_i \perp y_j \mid \mathbf{x}_j$ for $i \neq j$. But, I do not think that this notation is valid, is the correct notation  $y_i \perp y_j \mid \mathbf{x}_j, \mathbf{x}_i$. But then I do not think this correct as that statement only allows us to write:

$$
p(y_i, y_j \mid \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) = p(y_i \mid \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) p(y_j \mid \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j)
$$

But we really want:

$$
p(y_i, y_j \mid \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) = p(y_i \mid \mathbf{x}_i) p(y_j \mid \mathbf{x}_j)
$$

---

In summary, my question basically is, what is the correct way to write the conditional independent statements for linear regression?

Comment: You need *all* the responses to be uncorrelated with *all* the explanatory variables. You can find a great deal written about this here on CV: see [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+assumption+independ*+least+squares+score%3A5+is%3Aanswer).

Comment: Ok thank you, but I was wondering how you would write these independence statements mathematically. I was also wondering in [PRML](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) book what independence statement is used that allows them to write equation 3.10? And I am guessing that in a fixed design setting we can just say: assume responses are independent?

Comment: @whuber I also was wondering if you had a recommended book for a rigorous description of linear regression. That provides the assumptions, and the description of inferential statements that can be made under the assumptions. Thanks again.