# Which of the following is an independent event? , or are there different types of independent events?

Tags: self-study, independence

This is a high school math question:

There are 6 balls in a bag, and one of them is red, and it is marked #1, 2 yellow ones are marked #1 & #2, 3 blue ones are marked #1, #2, #3 respectively。Choose one from the bag at random and the ones that are independent events are:

A. E(red ball) and E( #1)

B. E(yellow ball) and E(#2)

C. E(blue ball) and E(#1)

D. E(blue ball) and E(#2)

The correct answer is D, and it is not hard to see why. By calculating P(blue ball) and P(#2), we get $P(blue ball) \times P(\#2)=P(blueball\cup\#2)$

But it seems to me that all four options are structually similar, so while it fits into the definition of independent events, it still feels weird that option D stands out simply by numerical concidence.

and doens't fit into my idea of independent events.  It's not like "7 heads in a row" and "the head or tail of the next coin thrown" are two independent events, which seems to have a more solid cause and effect grounding, as in the former event doesn't have any effect on the latter event.

Anyway, I obviously lack the ability to exactly describe what I feel so I am asking if people who have studied more statistics can help me out here.

Are "choice D are independent events" mean the same thing as "throwing dice and each round is independent from each other " mean the same thing when they talk about "independent"?

Comment: What does the notation "E(...)" mean?

Comment: It denotes Event. Is that is not the symbol commonly used?

Comment: It is not a common notation.  It was probably created by the textbook authors.  The book must have a definition of independence: have you tried to apply it?

Comment: Hi, I have delineated the definition as well as my understanding in the main post. I know the definition, and the answer to this specific question. And the reasoning behind the correct answer. I just want people to address my lingering suspision that the definition used in the textbook: i.e. P(A) *P(B)=P(AB) is "incomplete" BTW, added the self-study tag as requested

Comment: See my two answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21429/6633) which might help you a little in understanding the difference between physical independence and stochastic independence.